# Rejection-Sampling of Exponential Distribution

Tags: self-study, sampling, exponential-distribution, rejection-sampling

Consider the following question.

> Consider the generation of random numbers following an exponential distribution with some known mean. Give three reasons why the rejection-acceptance method would not be the preferred approach for generating random numbers for this distribution. What is the preferred approach?
>
> Assume a program is available to generate uniformly distributed random numbers between 0 and 1.

I'm not looking for direct answers to the question, but rather advice on how to go about solving it. I could not find a reason as to why the rejection method is not well suited for the exponential distribution. Thanks

Comment: I am not looking for a direct answer to the question itself. I've been stuck on this problem while studying for an exam, and can't seem to figure it out. I want someone to point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Can you say what you have done / understand so far?

Comment: It is not in the least obvious that rejection sampling couldn't work for an exponential distribution.  (Offhand I can think of a simple one with 69% efficiency.)  Why don't you try to implement a rejection sampler?  If you succeed with an efficient one, you will have learned more than whoever asked the question :-) while if you do not succeed you will acquire a good appreciation for what the difficulties might be.

Comment: @whuber Yes, rejection method can be used here. And I did read about it achieving around 69% accuracy. But I got the impression that the accuracy can't be increased any further, but I'm not sure how to prove it. I need some help in proving it (if it is the case).

Comment: Accuracy isn't the issue so much as speed.  Either you're generating exponentially-distributed variables or you're not; if you are, speed is what's left to consider.  Can you think of a method that a) isn't a rejection method, and b) requires fewer than 1/0.69 uniform random variates to be generated, on average, for each output exponential variate?

Answer (score 3):

The exponential distribution is one of the easiest to generate, because you can get its inverse CDF in closed form: Solving $u = F(x) = 1 - \exp\{-x/\theta\}$, you obtain $x = -\theta\log(1-u)$, implying that if $U_1,U_2,\ldots$ are independent uniforms, then $-\theta\log U_1, -\theta\log U_2, \ldots$ are independent exponentials with mean $\theta$. You can generate these without rejection. (Note: I replaced $1-U_j$ with $U_j$ because they both have the same distribution.)

That said, I think there are rejection methods that would have higher than 69% acceptance rate. All you need is a distribution with a fatter tail than the exponential, so that some multiple of its density dominates the exponential density. Generate a random variate from the fat-tailed distribution, and accept it with probability equal to the ratio of the exponential and the scaled fat-tailed density.

Comment: For any distribution there will be rejection procedures that come as close to 100% as you like--in theory. The issue is whether they are *fast and simple.* That comes down to efficiently generating realizations from a distribution having a similarly shaped PDF. (The 69% rate originates from the binary nature of the machines we use.) BTW, please take a look at [our policy](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) concerning [tag:self-study] questions.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I need to remember look at the tags.